# ContextRefresher in spring autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper

I have a java application in which one of the classes has ContextRefresher autowired:

```
public abstract class AbstractConfigurationPersister implements IConfigurationPersister {

    @Autowired
    private ContextRefresher contextRefresher;

    @Override
    public void forceRefresh() {
        contextRefresher.refresh();
    }

}
```

This autowired bean is giving me problems as from the logs, it says that paramater 1 has an unsatisfied dependency.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration$DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration':

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'application':

Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 
'ktc.tanalytics.prediction.PredictionBeanConfiguration':
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'configurationService' defined in ktc.tanalytics.commons.CommonsBeanConfiguration: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'zookeeperConfigurationPersister' defined in ktc.tanalytics.commons.CommonsBeanConfiguration: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'contextRefresher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'contextRefresher' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'refreshScope': 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]: 
Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now, I have checked the code of ContextRefresher in spring (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/refresh/ContextRefresher.java) and it receives two arguments.

I suppose that Spring is responsible of creating this ContextRefresher object since it is basically @Autowired. However I do not know why *parameter 1* is missing as the log says

Answer (score 0):

```
Factory method 'transactionAdvisor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

- As I focus on the above nested exception, probably *transactionAdvisor*
  is a factory method which tries to create something and while
  creating, it is performing some operation on null object.
- Just inspect or debug the method: transactionAdvisor , in your code.

Comment: transactionAdvisor is not part of my code. It's part of the spring framework https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java